# TypeError: left operand must be a str

Tags: python

I'm working on a project for CodeHS's intro to python course, and I cannot figure out why this section of code is producing an error message or not working at all.

I have tried removing the variable dashes, and the program works fine without it. For some reason, this new variable causes issues with the final part of the code.

```
secret_word = "banana"
x = 0
dashes = ""
wordlist = list(secret_word)

for x in range(len(secret_word)):
    dashes = dashes + "-"


def get_guess():
    while x < 1:
        guess = input("Guess: ")

        if len(guess) > 1:
            print "Your guess must have exactly one character!"
        elif not guess.islower():
            print "Your guess must be a lowercase letter"
        else:
            return guess


while dashes != secret_word:
    print dashes
    guess = get_guess()

    if guess in wordlist:
        print "That letter is in the word"
    else:
        print "That letter is not in the word"
```

I expect the program to ask for an input to guess a letter inside the word; however, the program either runs forever, or I experience an error message. This program is unfinished; any help to fix this error message or make it run more smoothly would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: why is your code double spaced..?

Comment: The code is double spaced because I am bad at formatting I guess. It looked weird when I initially put into this, so I double spaced.

Comment: Ok, I fixed your line-spacing to something more sensible ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You defined `x` here:

```py
secret_word = "banana"
x = 0
dashes = ""
wordlist = list(secret_word)
```

And reassigned values here:

```py
for x in range(len(secret_word)):
    dashes = dashes + "-"
```

Then the condition of the loop is always `False` here. So `get_guess()` does nothing.

```py
def get_guess():
    while x < 1:
        guess = input("Guess: ")
```

This is a nice example to show how short variable names and global variables are dangerous.